# Botão não roda o Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com dificuldades em fazer o botão responsável por gerar o alerta com o número do sorteio iniciar o javascript, estou utilizando o código abaixo para o javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $('#btnGnrt').click(function() {

    function sorteio_numero(nummin, nummax, numqtd){
        var amostra   = new Array(),
        lista     = new Array(),
        tamanho   = 0,
        aleatorio = 0;
        for(var i = nummin; i <= nummax; i++){
            amostra.push(i);
        }
        while( lista.length < numqtd ){

            tamanho = amostra.length;


            aleatorio = Math.floor( Math.random() * tamanho );


            lista.push( amostra.splice(aleatorio,1) ); 
        }
        return lista;
    }

    alert(sorteio_numero(1000,9999,1));

</script>
```

e o seguinte para o botão:

```
<div class="button">
    <br><button id="btnGnrt">Gerar Sorteio</button><br>
</div>
```

A página contém somente o botão e um header com o título, não consigo ver o motivo para o botão "não funcionar"

Comment: no lugar de `aleatorio`, não seria `resultado`?

Comment: Provavelmente tem a ver com o scopo, tente colocar `$('#btnGnrt').click(function() {}`
Dentro de um `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Sim, havia trocado os "aleatorio" por "resultado" mas deixei um passar, já corrigi a pergunta

Comment: Não veria nenhum problema em você chamar a `function` sorteio_numero no `onclick` inline do botão, mas... vai de gosto

Comment: Coloquei dentro do         $(document).ready(function(){}); e não resolveu, acho que vou tentar chamar no onclick mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há vários erros no seu código:

1. Você não fechou corretamente esse bloco `$('#btnGnrt').click(function() {`
2. `tamanho   = 0,`deve se terminar uma linha com `;`
3. `tamanho = amostra.length;`não há necessidade disso estar dentro do `while` sendo atribuído a cada interação.

***Obs:*** Modifiquei seu código para `js` puro.

## Funcionando

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(sorteio_numero(1000, 9999, 1));
})

function sorteio_numero(nummin, nummax, numqtd) {
    let amostra = [];
    let lista = [];
    let tamanho = 0;
    let aleatorio = 0;
    
    //Adiciona todos os números entre um Rang
    for (let i = nummin; i <= nummax; i++) {
        amostra.push(i);
    }
    
    tamanho = amostra.length;
    
    while (lista.length < numqtd) {
      aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho);
      lista.push(amostra.splice(aleatorio, 1));
    }
    return lista;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <br><button id="btnGnrt">Gerar Sorteio</button><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, `var` dentro de função não tem escopo global não.

Comment: @sam sim, cabei de ler sobre aqui, achei que tinha. enganei

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando fechar a estrutura do `click`, que comentei abaixo:

```js
$('#btnGnrt').click(function() {
    function sorteio_numero(nummin, nummax, numqtd) {
        var amostra = new Array(),
            lista = new Array(),
            tamanho = 0,
            aleatorio = 0;
        for (var i = nummin; i <= nummax; i++) {
            amostra.push(i);
        }
        while (lista.length < numqtd) {
            tamanho = amostra.length;
            aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * tamanho);
            lista.push(amostra.splice(aleatorio, 1));
        }
        return lista;
    }

    alert(sorteio_numero(1000, 9999, 1));
});  // essa estrutura aqui
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
    <br><button id="btnGnrt">Gerar Sorteio</button><br>
</div>
```